# Output multiple plots in Python for animation

Tags: python, animation

Im trying to animate a non-dispersive wave packet. My idea is to output the wave function at many different time points and then add individuals photos to make an animation. My Python code kind of the job but it repeats the previous plots in all following plots and i dont know how to fix it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

k = np.linspace(1,100,1000)
#x = np.linspace(-n<p.pi,np.pi,100)
x = np.linspace(0,70,71)
fac = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
result = []
n = 800
t = np.linspace(-150,150,n)
vp = -1
E0 = 1
w0 = 1
T = 10
def wave(k,x):
    return abs(np.sin(x-k))

def packet(E0,t,w0,T,x):
    return E0*np.cos(w0*(t+vp*x))*np.exp(-(t+vp*x)**2/T**2)

j = len(fac)-1
    #while j >= 0:
    #for i in range(len(k)):
    #   result.append(wave(k[i],x))
            #j -= 1

b = np.array(result)
c = np.sum(b,axis = 0)
    #plt.plot(x,c)
    #plt.show()

counter = 0
i=0
while counter <= 71:
    plt.plot(t,packet(E0,t,w0,T,i),label = 't = %d' %(i))
    plt.savefig("time%d.pdf" %i)
    i += 1
    counter += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite your cycle like this:

```
while counter <= 71:
    plt.cla() # clean current axis
    plt.plot(t, packet(E0,t,w0,T,i),label = 't = %d' %(i))
    plt.ylim([-1.1, 1.1]) # establish limits for better visualization
    plt.savefig("time%d.jpg" %i)
    i += 1
    counter += 1
```

also you can create [animation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html) according this example